# Python: return de uma função específica

Tags: python-3.x

**Como posso acessar o return da função `on_press(key)`?**

O programa abaixo captura as teclas digitadas.
Abra, por exemplo, o bloco de notas e digite **teste** e teclhe **Enter**

O resultado na lista deverá ser: **`lista = ['t','e','s','t','e','<key.esc>']`**

**Podem me dar uma dica?
Agradeço.**

```
from pynput import keyboard


def on_press(key):
    lista = []
    try:
        texto = '{0}'.format(key.char)
        lista.append(texto)
    except AttributeError:
        texto = '<{0}>'.format(key)
        lista.append(texto)
    return lista

def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False


# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Por que não deixa a variável `lista` no escopo global?

Comment: Estava dando erro. Eu havia tentado. Bem, a resposta do colega abaixo funcionou e, inclusive aceitou (funcionou) em colocar a variável no escopo global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tanto usar uma variável global, quanto uma classe. Pessoalmente eu prefiro a ideia de uma classe:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


class Keyload():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista = []
        with Listener(
                on_press=self.on_press,
                on_release=self.on_release) as listener:
            listener.join()

    def on_press(self,key):
        print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
        self.lista.append('{0}'.format(key))

    def on_release(self,key):
        if key == Key.esc:
            # Stop listener
            return False

dados = Keyload()
print(dados.lista)
```

Mas se ainda preferir utilizar uma variável global:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

global lista

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(key))
    lista.append('{0}'.format(key))

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
lista = []
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()

print(lista)
```

Comment: Eu havia tentado colocar a variável no escopo global, mas estava dando erro. Mas agora funcionou. Mas a melhor ideia é usar a classe mesmo. Obrigado.